# How to select rows based on unique column

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

I have table with values as

```
    ColumnA   ColumnB

    ASD       A
    CSD       B
    DSD       C
    ESD       D
    FSD       D
    GSD       D
```

Column A is primary key, I need result as

```
    ColumnA   ColumnB

    ASD       A
    CSD       B
    DSD       C
    ESD       D
```

I want all unique values from column B & their associated first values columnA.

I tried few queries & looked on Google but couldn't find ant solution .

Thanks,
Rohit.

Comment: What queries did you try? What results did they give?

Answer (score 3):

First is First in key order (i.e. alphabetically).

```
SELECT MIN(ColumnA) AS ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ColumnB
```

You've tagged both MySQL and Oracle for some reason. The above will work in both.

Oracle also has analytical functions that can help with [this general type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) of query.

Answer (score 2):

```
select min(columna) columna, columnb
from mytable
group by columnb;
```

Answer (score 2):

With analytics (Oracle):

```
SQL> WITH tab AS (
  2     SELECT 'ASD' columnA, 'A' columnB FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 'CSD', 'B' FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 'DSD', 'C' FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 'ESD', 'D' FROM DUAL
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 'FSD', 'D' FROM DUAL
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 'GSD', 'D' FROM DUAL
  8  )
  9  SELECT columnA, columnB
 10    FROM (SELECT columnA, columnB,
 11                 rank() over(PARTITION BY columnB ORDER BY columnA) rnk
 12            FROM tab)
 13   WHERE rnk = 1;

COLUMNA COLUMNB
------- -------
ASD     A
CSD     B
DSD     C
ESD     D
```

Comment: I like it: easier to change if the inferred definition of 'first' turns out to be incorrect. Out of interest, Oracle doesn't require a name for a derived table, then? Why did you choose to use a derived table over a CTE?

Comment: @onedaywhen : I'm not sure I fully understand your questions since I'm not familiar with the SQL Server vocabulary. Oracle doesn't require an alias when using a subquery (is it the same as a derived table?). The `WITH` clause is called a subquery factoring in Oracle, I find it's useful to give a small self-contained example: you can run the query in your environment without having to create any additional object (You can't create #temporary tables that will self-destruct when the session ends in Oracle).

Comment: I'm actually using Standard SQL terms :) Your subquery that defines the table naned `tab` (`SELECT...UNION ALL SELECT...`) is known as a common table expression (CTE) and your subquery that further queries  the `tab` CTE is known as a derived table. But I'll try re-phrasing my question in Oracle terms...

Comment: Your subquery `(SELECT columnA, columnB, ... FROM tab)` can be written using a second WITH clause subquery factoring e.g. `WITH tab AS (<first subquery>), tab2 AS (<second subquery>) SELECT columnA, columnB FROM tab2 WHERE rnk = 1;` -- so I'm wondering why you used two subqueries in two different ways. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(ColumnA) as ColumnA,ColumnB from table
group by ColumnB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #t_Val
(
    ColumnA VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY
,   ColumnB CHAR(1) NOT NULL
)

INSERT #t_Val
SELECT 'ASD' ,  'A'
UNION
SELECT 'CSD' ,  'B'
UNION
SELECT 'DSD' ,  'C'
UNION
SELECT 'ESD' ,  'D'
UNION
SELECT 'FSD' ,  'D'
UNION
SELECT 'GSD' ,  'D'


SELECT  MIN(ColumnA),ColumnB
FROM #t_Val
GROUP BY ColumnB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing the same thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(ColumnA)
    OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnB
          ORDER BY ColumnA) AS ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM tbl
```

This has the advantage of being usable with more than one column (i.e. where the GROUP BY method doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

CREATE TABLE `tbl_test` (
  `col1` varchar(5) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(5) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`col1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl_test` VALUES ('ASD', 'A');
INSERT INTO `tbl_test` VALUES ('CSD', 'B');
INSERT INTO `tbl_test` VALUES ('DSD', 'C');
INSERT INTO `tbl_test` VALUES ('ESD', 'D');
INSERT INTO `tbl_test` VALUES ('FSD', 'D');
INSERT INTO `tbl_test` VALUES ('GSD', 'D');

---

SELECT DISTINCT (
col2
), col1
FROM tbl_test
GROUP BY col2
LIMIT 0 , 30;